# How can I optimize these T-SQL queries?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, query-optimization

I have four sql variables that were calculated in the exact same way, except one condition on each query :

```
  C.CenterID = @CenterID
  C.CenterNo IN (SELECT CenterNo from Registry.Vol1_5)
  C.CenterNo IN (SELECT CenterNo from Registry.Vol6_10)
  C.CenterNo IN (SELECT CenterNo from Registry.Vol11)
```

My code is here:

```
DECLARE @MyCenterAllComplications INT;
DECLARE @Total5AllComplications INT;
DECLARE @Total6_10AllComplications INT;
DECLARE @Total11AllComplications INT;   


SET @MyCenterAllComplications = (SELECT count(*) FROM ECLS.Runs R

 INNER JOIN Registry.Patients P on R.PatientId = P.PatientId
 INNER JOIN Registry.CenterPatients CP ON CP.PatientId = P.PatientId
 INNER JOIN Registry.Centers C on C.CenterId = CP.CenterId

where 1 = 1

 AND NOT R.RunId IN (select RD.RunId from ECLS.RunDetails RD 
  INNER JOIN ECLS.ModeCodes MC ON RD.Mode = MC.Code AND MC.Abbreviation IN ('AVCO2R', 'VVCO2R')
  )
 AND C.CenterID = @CenterID
 AND R.SupportType = @SupportType
 AND NOT R.CompletedBy IS NULL
 AND NOT R.TimeOn IS NULL
 AND DATEDIFF(year, R.timeOn, GETDATE()) < 10
 AND DATEDIFF(day, P.Birthdate, R.timeOn) <= 30
); 

SET @Total5AllComplications = (SELECT count(*) FROM ECLS.Runs R

 INNER JOIN Registry.Patients P on R.PatientId = P.PatientId
 INNER JOIN Registry.CenterPatients CP ON CP.PatientId = P.PatientId
 INNER JOIN Registry.Centers C on C.CenterId = CP.CenterId

where 1 = 1

 AND NOT R.RunId IN (select RD.RunId from ECLS.RunDetails RD 
  INNER JOIN ECLS.ModeCodes MC ON RD.Mode = MC.Code AND MC.Abbreviation IN ('AVCO2R', 'VVCO2R')
  )
 AND C.CenterNo IN (SELECT CenterNo from Registry.Vol1_5)
 AND R.SupportType = @SupportType
 AND NOT R.CompletedBy IS NULL
 AND NOT R.TimeOn IS NULL
 AND DATEDIFF(year, R.timeOn, GETDATE()) < 10
 AND DATEDIFF(day, P.Birthdate, R.timeOn) <= 30
);

SET @Total6_10AllComplications = (SELECT count(*) FROM ECLS.Runs R

 INNER JOIN Registry.Patients P on R.PatientId = P.PatientId
 INNER JOIN Registry.CenterPatients CP ON CP.PatientId = P.PatientId
 INNER JOIN Registry.Centers C on C.CenterId = CP.CenterId

where 1 = 1

 AND NOT R.RunId IN (select RD.RunId from ECLS.RunDetails RD 
  INNER JOIN ECLS.ModeCodes MC ON RD.Mode = MC.Code AND MC.Abbreviation IN ('AVCO2R', 'VVCO2R')
  )
 AND C.CenterNo IN (SELECT CenterNo from Registry.Vol6_10)
 AND R.SupportType = @SupportType
 AND NOT R.CompletedBy IS NULL
 AND NOT R.TimeOn IS NULL
 AND DATEDIFF(year, R.timeOn, GETDATE()) < 10
 AND DATEDIFF(day, P.Birthdate, R.timeOn) <= 30
);

 SET @Total11AllComplications = (SELECT count(*) FROM ECLS.Runs R

 INNER JOIN Registry.Patients P on R.PatientId = P.PatientId
 INNER JOIN Registry.CenterPatients CP ON CP.PatientId = P.PatientId
 INNER JOIN Registry.Centers C on C.CenterId = CP.CenterId

where 1 = 1

 AND NOT R.RunId IN (select RD.RunId from ECLS.RunDetails RD 
  INNER JOIN ECLS.ModeCodes MC ON RD.Mode = MC.Code AND MC.Abbreviation IN ('AVCO2R', 'VVCO2R')
  )
 AND C.CenterNo IN (SELECT CenterNo from Registry.Vol11)
 AND R.SupportType = @SupportType
 AND NOT R.CompletedBy IS NULL
 AND NOT R.TimeOn IS NULL
 AND DATEDIFF(year, R.timeOn, GETDATE()) < 10
 AND DATEDIFF(day, P.Birthdate, R.timeOn) <= 30
);
```

How can I calculate all these variables

```
@MyCenterAllComplications,
@Total5AllComplications,
@Total6_10AllComplications,
@Total11AllComplications
```

At the same time, by using one query? Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: The where 1 = 1 isn't needed, i'm unsure about combining all selects into one query however you can pull back the initial duplicated select statements into a temporary table to save retrieving that 4 times

Comment: please check here on how to improve question :http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT count(cID.ID)
     , count(Registry.Vol1_5.CenterNo)
     , count(Registry.Vol6_10.CenterNo)
     , count(on Registry.Vol11.CenterNo)
FROM ECLS.Runs R
INNER JOIN Registry.Patients P 
        on R.PatientId = P.PatientId
       AND R.SupportType = @SupportType
       AND NOT R.CompletedBy IS NULL
       AND NOT R.TimeOn IS NULL
       AND DATEDIFF(year, R.timeOn, GETDATE()) < 10
       AND DATEDIFF(day, P.Birthdate, R.timeOn) <= 30
       AND NOT R.RunId IN (select RD.RunId 
                           from ECLS.RunDetails RD 
                           INNER JOIN ECLS.ModeCodes MC 
                            ON RD.Mode = MC.Code 
                           AND MC.Abbreviation IN ('AVCO2R', 'VVCO2R')
                          )
INNER JOIN Registry.CenterPatients CP ON CP.PatientId = P.PatientId
INNER JOIN Registry.Centers C on C.CenterId = CP.CenterId 
LEFT JOIN (select @CenterID as ID
          ) cID
             on cID.ID                   = C.CenterNo 
LEFT JOIN Registry.Vol1_5
            on Registry.Vol1_5.CenterNo  = C.CenterNo 
LEFT JOIN Registry.Vol6_10
            on Registry.Vol6_10.CenterNo = C.CenterNo 
LEFT JOIN Registry.Vol11
            on Registry.Vol11.CenterNo   = C.CenterNo
```

Answer (score 2):

You can combine all these queries into 1 using conditional aggregation with `CASE EXPRESSION` :

```
  SELECT @MyCenterAllComplications = SUM(MyCenterAllComplications) ,
         @Total5AllComplications = SUM(Total5AllComplications),
  .......
FROM(
    SELECT CASE WHEN C.CenterID = @CenterID THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as MyCenterAllComplications , 
           CASE WHEN C.CenterNo IN (SELECT CenterNo from Registry.Vol1_5) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as Total5AllComplications  ,
       ....
    FROM ECLS.Runs R
     INNER JOIN Registry.Patients P on R.PatientId = P.PatientId
     INNER JOIN Registry.CenterPatients CP ON CP.PatientId = P.PatientId
     INNER JOIN Registry.Centers C on C.CenterId = CP.CenterId
    where 1 = 1
     AND NOT R.RunId IN (select RD.RunId from ECLS.RunDetails RD 
      INNER JOIN ECLS.ModeCodes MC ON RD.Mode = MC.Code AND MC.Abbreviation IN ('AVCO2R', 'VVCO2R')
      )
     AND R.SupportType = @SupportType
     AND NOT R.CompletedBy IS NULL
     AND NOT R.TimeOn IS NULL
     AND DATEDIFF(year, R.timeOn, GETDATE()) < 10
     AND DATEDIFF(day, P.Birthdate, R.timeOn) <= 30)
```

Further than that, you should post the explain plan of this query and tables structure so we can tell you if there are any indexes missing from your tables.

Comment: Thank you very much. Unfortunately, I have got an error message :"Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery." related to the condition  @Total5AllComplications = COUNT(CASE WHEN C.CenterNo IN (SELECT CenterNo from Registry.Vol1_5) THEN 1 END), and similar.

Comment: I am sorry, but I have errors in  SELECT @MyCenterAllComplications = SUM(MyCenterAllComplications) and similar: "Invalid column name MyCenterAllComplications" etc.

Comment: Then you didn't alias them properly, look at the inner select `SELECT CASE .... AS MyCenter...` . Do it for each variable

Comment: I did, please see the code: 
    `SELECT CASE WHEN C.CenterID = @CenterID THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as MyCenterAllComplications , 
           CASE WHEN C.CenterNo IN (SELECT CenterNo from Registry.Vol1_5) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as Total5AllComplications,
     CASE WHEN C.CenterNo IN (SELECT CenterNo from Registry.Vol6_10) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as Total6_10AllComplications,
           CASE WHEN C.CenterNo IN (SELECT CenterNo from Registry.Vol11) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as Total11AllComplications
    FROM ECLS.Runs R`

Comment: @alenan2013 Update your post with the new query you are using, and the full error it produces.

Answer (score 0):

It is not sufficient just know your query, it need to know how to is structured your database.

A general response could be: read the query execution plan and check if an index is required:
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178071(v=sql.105).aspx

To view the execution plan, click the Execution plan tab in the results pane. The graphical execution plan output in SQL Server Management Studio is read from right to left and from top to bottom. Each query in the batch that is analyzed is displayed, including the cost of each query as a percentage of the total cost of the batch.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. I have found the Execution plan, I will try to understand it.